# RabbitMQ - cannot delete queue

Tags: rabbitmq

We had a network network partition and RabbitMQ ended up in "split brain".

After the cluster recovered, I have a queue that I cant delete. In the mgmt. interface the queue is just listed with "?", and I'm unable to delete it from using mgmt. interface or from commandline.

I have tried to remove the node "sh-mq-cl1a-04" from the cluster, but the queue remains in the cluster.

Comment: Any error messages in the logs when you try to delete the queue? I think it would be better to reach out to us here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Comment: No noting - the command just hangs until i kill the process

Comment: have you found any solution for this. I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue where I couldn't delete some queues, and the solution listed here worked for me: https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Queue-cant-be-deleted-or-purged-in-RabbitMQ

I ssh'd onto one of the nodes in my cluster (the one where the queue is hosted is probably best), sudo'd as `root`, and then ran this command:

```
rabbitmqctl eval '{ok, Q} = rabbit_amqqueue:lookup(rabbit_misc:r(<<"VHOST">>, queue, <<"QUEUE">>)), rabbit_amqqueue:delete_crashed(Q).'
```

You'll need to replace `VHOST` with your virtual host name, and `QUEUE` with your queue name (which I realize it might be tricky to figure out, in your situation).

Comment: That's a great point, thanks for the reminder! I will update my answer.

Comment: my 2 cents: I also connected to the pod and ran:
`rabbitmqctl delete_queue <queue:name>`
which is a bit simpler